Is there a measure addon that has the functionality that I tried to create in this addon
The normal ruler in blender has nice functionality, except that you cant lock the measurement to vertices/faces/edges. I need a addon that does this (for 3d printing purposes).
I tried recreating my own, but does someone know if this functionality is in some addon already?
https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/1gqed8c/i_have_been_working_with_a_measure_addon_in/

The MeasureIt addon comes with Blender and does exactly this.

As far as i know, measureit cannot do this. You can only measure between vertices. Like using a guide point for measuring is not possible, unless you extrude a vertex there

Can you explain how the second drawn line can be done in MeasureIt, without a vertex being at the endpoint?

You can use the link function in MeasureIt to connect objects other than vertices such as empties.  This might be close to the functionality you are describing.

this sounds very tedious, creating an empty and positioning it just to make a measurement

After seeing the comment by @common_goldfish regarding empties and part of an old answer on BlenderArtists: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-measure-between-2-objects-using-measureit/1156781 I am rewriting this.
IMHO it isn't an overly difficult way to update the dimension change on the X-axis with Blender's improved snapping. I don't think there is a way to do this dynamically on the X-axis between two objects when they are offset on the Y-axis. Any of the other changes shown in your linked video the MeasureIt Tool can do without any extra effort.
Create 2 empties. I left them huge for illustration. In MeasureIT Tools Click link:

With Vertex Snapping on for all measuring, snap one of the empties to a vertex on an object:

Select the other empty and in this case press G->X and move the mouse pointer to the vertex on the other cube. The orange box is the location of the mouse pointer:

X-axis dimension with no changes to geometry:

X-axis dimension after change to geometry and selecting empty and pressing G->X:

Object moved on Z-axis and pressed G->X and G->Z. The empty will go where you place the cursor. This image is different, because I messed up the original:

Example operation on one object: Select 2 vertices and click Segment:

Move geometry and the dimension changes:


So, if you move the vertex or the cube from where the line was initiated, it doesnt stay locked to the vertex, so you have to measure the distance again, which is why i tried to develop this addon

It doesnt really change dynamically

I rewrote the answer. Maybe it will be of some help. See the rewrite about the dimension changing  dynamically on the X-axis.

alright, seems like alot of extra steps to do the that though, messing about with empties etc
